# Null Object Pattern with repository pattern and unit of work

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using a unit of work to retrieve records / record form database, i am trying to implement some kind of a null object design pattern so that i dont have to check every-time if the returned object is null or not. I have tried searching online however i have not land on any good explanation on how to best achieve this in this current situation, I am familiar with the traditional approach for Null Object Design Pattern where you create a copy null class with hard coded properties and methods and return either the class or null-class based on outcome of the search in Db. however I feel that with the unit of work and repository patterns this approach is not valid. here is the class.

```
public class HR_Setup_Location 
{
   public string Street1 { get; set; }
   public string Street2 { get; set; }
   public string City { get; set; }
   public string State { get; set; }
   public string Country { get; set; } 
   public string FullAddress{
      get { return $"{Street1} {City} {Country}"; }
  }
   [ForeignKey("Setup")]
   public int SetupId { get; set; }
   public virtual Setup Setup { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<HR_Setup_OfficeEvent> HR_Setup_OfficeEvents { get; set; }
}
```

I tried the following , which is doing the job for now, however i appreciate your feedback on the approach if you have tried something similar in a similar situation. and what is the best way to address null objects in this pattern.

```
 public interface ISetupLocationRepository : IRepository<HR_Setup_Location>
{
    HR_Setup_Location GetById(int LocationId);

}

public class SetupLocationRepository : Repository<HR_Setup_Location>, ISetupLocationRepository
{
    private readonly DataBaseContext context;

    public SetupLocationRepository(DataBaseContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }


    public HR_Setup_Location GetById(int LocationId)
    {
        HR_Setup_Location Obj = context.HR_Setup_Locations.Where(p => p.HR_Setup_LocationId == LocationId).FirstOrDefault();
        if (Obj != null)
        {
            return Obj;
        }
        else
        {
            HR_Setup_Location Obj2 = new HR_Setup_Location()
            {
                HR_Setup_LocationId = -1,
                Street1 = string.Empty,
                Street2 = string.Empty,
                City = string.Empty,
                State = string.Empty,
                Country = string.Empty,
                SetupId = -1,
            };
            Obj2.HR_Setup_OfficeEvents = null;
            return Obj2;
        }
    }

}
```

Then with the unit of work I am trying to access the location address by calling:

```
string LocationName = Vacancy.HR_Setup_LocationId.HasValue ? unitOfWork.SetupLocations.GetById(Vacancy.HR_Setup_LocationId.Value).FullAddress : "";
```

so basically if no id is based it will return an empty string, and if an id is passed but the record is no longer available in DataBase then the null object return empty for Fulladdress

Comment: If you have code that works (even if only inelegantly) and you have (practical, non-subjective) questions on how to improve it, that's what [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is for. If on the other hand the code doesn't work, it's good for SO, but you'll need to be specific on how it doesn't work.